# C# RegEx not working with multiline modifier

Tags: c#, regex

I have been matching different patterns but the regex in C# seems to be complication.

My string is like this

```
AT+CMGL="REC UNREAD"
OK
```

It has 2 more spaces after the OK. But even if I just match until OK, it's not succeeding.
I want to match the whole string like this:

```
string pattern = @"AT\+CMGL=""REC UNREAD""\r\n";
pattern += "OK\r\n";
pattern += "\r\n";
Match match = Regex.Match(content, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (match.Success)
   return;
```

Comment: Is your string definitely `\r\n` and not `\n`? It [works for me](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=AT%5c%2bCMGL%3d%22REC+UNREAD%22%5cr%5cnOK%5cr%5cn%5cr%5cn&i=AT%2bCMGL%3d%22REC+UNREAD%22%0d%0aOK%0d%0a%0d%0a&o=m).

Comment: I even tried `\r`, `\r\n` and `\n` still they do not match.

Comment: I often use a pattern like `[\r\n]+` to match newlines when I am not sure exactly what characters will be present. I also use `[\r\n]*$` to match an optional newline at the end of a string. A downside of these forms is that they can match more than one newline.

Comment: That's also a good one. However, this one is fixed to \r\r\n. Thank you for that additional knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I found out after more than a day of work that there's a `Regex.Escape(String) Method`. With grouping and Regex.Escape() I was able to identify whats inside.
I found out it has "\r\r\n" at the rightmost. So the regex is:

```
@"AT\+CMGL=""REC UNREAD""\r\r\n";
pattern += "OK\r\n";
pattern += "\r\n$";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\s*` to match multiple spaces.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"AT\+CMGL=""REC UNREAD""\s*OK\s*";
        string input = @"AT+CMGL=""REC UNREAD""
OK

";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```